# A question about many-one reducibility of two sets

Tags: computer-science, computability, recursion

We want to show that $ \big\{x:W_{x}$ is finite }$=Fin \leq _m Cof=\big\{x : W_{x}$  is  cofinite}. But I really have not any idea.

Would be grateful for your help.

Comment: What does the notation $W_x$ mean?

Comment: $W_x$ is the set of all $y\in N$ such that $\varphi_x(y)$ converges.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $T$ is some Turing machine, and construct this $U$:

```
read (y,n);
simulate T on input y for n steps;
if T halts after exactly n steps
   then loop forever
   else halt
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I rather need a mathematical proof! It's an exercise in the Barry Cooper's "Computability Theory" book.

Comment: @Aref: This is the beginning of a proof. I'm leaving it for you to complete it.